# AngularDart CurrentInstruction

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

I am trying to update angular2 to latest version. Several of the functions are missing

I would like to know what is the alternate for the following function

```
final RouteParams _params;
String get routeName => _router.currentInstruction.component.routeName;
```

How to get routeName from new AngularDart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to access current component route anymore.

I don't know what you want to do exactly and how you define your routeName, but you probably need to use `additionalData` of `RoutePath` or `RouteDefinition`

```dart
class AdditionalRouteData {
  final String routeName;

  const AdditionalRouteData({this.routeName});
}

final routePath = RoutePath(
    path: '/',
    additionalData: AdditionalRouteData(routeName: 'Home'),
);


// then get it that way
(router.current.routePath.additionalData as AdditionalRouteData).routeName;
```

However, if your routeName is dynamic, you must find a new way to access it (without the router, using a service via dependency injection)

Comment: Thanks I had tried your idea, working fine.